# why when i put what i pass in props in useState i have an empty array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, is-empty

in the child component , I can read the props data in the console.log but when i put the state data in useState and i put the state in a console.log , i have an empty array and i don't understand why ?

```
    const FicheUserDisplay = ({ data }) => {
console.log("-->data<--");
console.log(data);

const [state, setState] = useState(data);
console.log("-->State");

console.log("state dans composant Fiche User")
console.log(state);

  return (
```

[image]

Comment: Please try manipulating the state using a `React.useEffect`. While you are mounting the component you should add the prop data to the state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way, you are using antipattern for react environment

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setState(data);
    }
  }, [data]);
```

Comment: Can you point to resources that highight this as an anti-pattern ? ( Initializing a useState with values received by props ).